# AngularJS UI Router nested states are not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I am trying to have nested states in UI-Router. But with no luck. I keep getting the following error.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module AdminPortal due to:
Error: Cannot combine: component|bindings|componentProvider with: templateProvider|templateUrl|template|notify|async|controller|controllerProvider|controllerAs|resolveAs in stateview: '$default@auth.portal.dashboard'
```

This is my route, when I go to the :

```
$stateProvider
        .state('auth.portal', {
            templateUrl: '/admin/dist/templates/portal.tpl.html'
        })
        .state('auth.portal.dashboard', {
            url: '/dashboard',
            component: 'dashboardComponent',
            templateUrl: '/admin/dist/templates/dashboard.tpl.html'
        });
```

**portal.tpl.html**

```
<h1>Portal</h1>
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

Basicaly I want to load *portal.tpl.html* and use the *ui-view* in that document for the *dashboard.tpl.html*.

I already checked out the [GitHub Docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views), [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/7FD5Wf?p=preview) Plunkr and some other questions on Stack Overflow, but still not working.

Comment: As I can see error clearly stated that. you should remove `templateUrl` property from state definition which makes more sense to me.. as component will take care of URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you don't need to specify tempale in your State router as you are using components now. Components should have the template definitions. Here is the link for more info
https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component

Comment: I thought it didn't matter where I defined that, because usualy I have the exact same templateUrl in the component as you suggest. But apperantly when I define it in the component it works! Thank you!